# Алгоритм Дейкстры для второго наименьшего пути

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, графы, теория

Задача: найти и вывести первый и второй (который может совпадать с первым) наименьший путь в графе. И если с первым пунктом всё понятно (алгоритм Дейкстры), то как нужно поступить с вторым путем (используя этот же алгоритм Дейкстры)? Поиск ответвлений с большим или равным значением,чем в 1 пути не всегда верен т.к. второй наименьший путь может идти совсем другой дорогой. Может быть есть какой-то лучший алгоритм?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате, приведите пример вашей текущей реализации и т. д.

Comment: В основном это был теоретический вопрос(что видно из тегов).Но если нужно конкретнее то без проблем.Сам код взял с http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/ (с\с++).Проблема в том, что алгоритм находит только 1 значение соответствующее минимальному значению из одного узла в другой(функция mindistance).При этом поиск второго минимального значения в этой функции (через if) не помогает т.к. второй наименьший путь может проходить через другие узлы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да есть, существует несколько способов решения. Самый простой - находим кратчайший путь и перебираем в цикле ребро, которого не будет во 2 пути. Из всех таких оставить оптимальный, псевдокод:

```
val second_path = inf;
val opt_path =  Dejkstra();
for (edge : opt_path){
    edge.del();
    second_path = min(second_path, Dejkstra() );  
    edge.add();
}
```

Сложность что-то порядка `O( N*(N*logN + M) );` Если надо быстрее, то есть способ.
Рассмотрим оставное дерево, образованное всеми оптимальными путями от 1 вершины до остальных. (Почем дерево думаю очевидно). После чего мы должны на путь из 1 в K к примеру, использовать РОВНО 1 ребро не из дерева. Дальше - динамика по дереву. Опишу идею: либо мы поднимаемся выше по этой ветке дерева, либо мы перепрыгиваем на соседнее, в любом случае у нас есть оптимальное значение пути которое мы момжем использовать.

Сложность: сложность Дейкстры = O(N log N + M).

Кстати оба алгоритма ищут все 2 пути из выбранной вершины.

Answer (score 1):

Решено, подсказали решение алгоритмом - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm либо второе решение(используя алгоритм Дейкстры) - найти минимальный путь до всех соседей целевого узла, выбрать из них самый минимальный , проверить совпадает ли он с 1 минимальным.Если совпадает - найти следущий минимальный.